# выровнять колонку по центру

Tags: bootstrap

Как выровнять колонку по центру в фреймворке Bootstrap? Только начал изучать. Пример кода.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 my-col">
            <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="image1" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 my-col">
            <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="image2" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 my-col">
            <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="image3" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Здесь три колонки выравниваются хорошо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь одна колонка выравнивается по левому краю. Как ее выровнять по центру? Есть ли в фреймворке Bootstrap такое средство?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: колонки или содержимое?

Comment: На первой картинке выровнены колонки или содержимое? Наверное колонки.

Comment: сарказм? с таким вопросом? :) это забавно :):):) Код, который Вы предоставили, показывает первую картинку. Вторая картинка может быть либо если код изменен (тогда покажите), либо если размер экрана... Вобщем, что делали межд двумя картинками? Еще может стиль `.my-col` повлиять. Его бы тоже увидеть...

Comment: Уважаемый cyadvert, на второй картинке размер экрана естественно изменен. В коде `col-sm-12` при изменении экрана, три колонки превращаются в одну. Вот эта одна колонка не по центру экрана.

Comment: `.my-col {
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}`

Comment: судя по `col-sm-12 col-xs-12` Вы хотите, чтобы при уменьшении экрана меньше чем `width: 992px` колонки превращались в строки. Потому что bootstrap ставит `col-*-12` в `width: 100%`. остается центровать содержимое. А этого вы ему нигде не говорите, вот он и не центрует картинки, оставляя их слева...

Comment: cyadvert!!! Это понятно. Что нужно сделать? Какой класс подключить?

Comment: я обновил свой ответ - поробуйте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Правка/замечание (дек. 2018) - приведенный ниже код работает для Bootstrap 3.*
*Bootstrap 4 имеет другие классы*

Используйте вот этот HTML (добавлен класс `.text-center`)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 my-col text-center">
            <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="image1" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 my-col text-center">
            <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="image2" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 my-col text-center">
            <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="image3" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

И поменяйте аттрибут `display` у картинок

```
.my-col .img-responsive {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Уважаемый cyadvert, добавил text-center, все тоже самое.

Comment: Уважаемый cyadvert! Большое спасибо. Достаточно сделать так
`.img-responsive {
 display: inline-block;
}`
Но я то думал, что у Bootstrap есть какой-то специальный класс или он сам, автоматически будет выравнивать, например как на певом фото. Он же как-то три колонки выравнивает. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: если сработало - то, чтобы закрыть вопрос, ставьте стрелочку и галочку на ответе